# Count Number of Occurences of Tag in XML FIle

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to count the number of times the "genre" tag occurs in some xml files. If found more than once I want to print that more than one was found in the filename it's found in. The code below writes that every file has the genre tag greater than 1 and writes "genre count is > 1" for every file. How can I run the code separately for each xml file?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mypath = "somepath"

def check_genre():
    genrelist = []
    count = 0
    
    try:
        for base, dirs, file in os.walk(mypath):
            dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d[0] == '.']  
            for file in file:
                file = os.path.join(base, file)
                if file.endswith(".".lower()):
                    tree = ET.parse(file)
                    root = tree.getroot()   
                    gene_tag = root.find("genre")       
                    for genre_tag in root.iter('genre'):
                        count +=1

                    if count > 1:   
                        print ("genre count is > 1", file)
```

Comment: Why are you clobbering your list of files with `for file in file`?

Comment: I'd answer you if I knew what you were asking.